# Mapping json field with database table field

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, json

How can a json id and database table id be mapped in ruby on rails and the output of the result be shown on UI. I have a collection of entries in my database say for id, name, url, code, and on UI i have implemented a table whose values are from Json field. I need to fetch data from database for url and code on UI using map concepts in rails.

Example : 
Json field :  [position":"1","name":"Bitcoin","change24":"-2.59 %","currency":"usd","id":"btc"]. My database has url and id, where id is the same value as in json. All thats needed is to map the id in-order to get the corresponding url on UI.

Comment: Could you be more specific, may give an example? What are your input values and what would you expect as an output?

Comment: Have edited the content.

Comment: Add a helper method, use it in UI, pass the JSON ID to get the URL from DB. please add some code samples that you have tried, so that its easy to sort out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So is this something you are going for?

```
@json_data.map! do |json_item|
  db_item = @database_data.detect{|dbi| dbi['id']==json_item['id']}
  json_item['url'] = db_item['url'] if db_item
end
```